# PHP Symfony 4, fopen - not working relative path

Tags: php, file, symfony

Symfony 4

I want to open JPEG file and get it content. I am calling a function in file
`myProject/src/DataFixtures/UserFixtures.php`

```
$avatar = stream_get_contents(fopen('src/DataFixtures/avatars/my_avatar.jpeg', 'rb'));
```

I am getting an error `"file not found"`. But there is a file in location `src/DataFixtures/avatars/my_avatar.jpeg`. I don't know why the relative path is not working.

Comment: most likely because `fopen()` start in the working directory, which would be the fodler `public`... Thus you need to get out of `public` first.. So `'../src/DataFixtures/avatars/my_avatar.jpeg'` should works better

Comment: this is because you are using a relative path. If you are inside the file "myProject/src/DataFixtures/UserFixtures.php" and call fopen with "src/DataFixtures/avatars/my_avatar.jpeg" path, what you will try to open is "myProject/src/DataFixtures/src/DataFixtures/avatars/my_avatar.jpeg". You either give it a full path from the root by defining a project root in some kind of config file, or add backtraces "../../src/Data..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not planning using those files outside the mentioned directory - the following snippet should do:

```
$avatar = stream_get_contents(fopen(__DIR__ . '/avatars/my_avatar.jpeg', 'rb'));
```

However, if you DO plan to access those files from elsewhere - you should rather consider having that directory defined globally or injected somehow. For example - you could have that path defined under your `parameters.yml` and then you could get its value as a container parameter.

Comment: Thank you. It works. It's the only solution from this topic that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

change url to just my_avatar.jpeg beacuse it is in same folder as php file 
change this

```
$avatar = stream_get_contents(fopen('src/DataFixtures/avatars/my_avatar.jpeg', 'rb'));
```

to

```
$avatar = stream_get_contents(fopen('my_avatar.jpeg', 'rb'));`
```